# how to process a complex php array submitted by a form?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

i have this array submitted using an extjs form:

```
$submittedFormaddress = array('city' => array('london', 'boston', 'paris'),
'country' => array('UK', 'USA', 'FRANCE'),
'zip' => array('22222', '33333', '44444'));
```

How can i automatically create below array from  $submittedFormaddress?

```
$clientAddress=array('address1'=>array
('city'=>'london','country'=>'UK','zip'=>'2222'),'address2'=>array
('city'=>'boston','country'=>'USA','zip'=>'3333'),'address3'=>array
('city'=>'paris','country'=>'FRANCE','zip'=>'44444'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through and drill down.

I tried to make each variable name descriptive:

```
<?php
foreach ($submittedFormaddress as $address_part => $part_array) {
    foreach($part_array as $index => $name) {
        $clientAddress['address' . ($index + 1)][$address_part] = $name;
    }
}
?>
```

[**Working Example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/34pjah)

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($submittedFormaddress['city']); $i++)
{
    $clientAddress['address'.$i] = array(
        'city' => $submittedFormaddress['city'][$i],
        'country' => $submittedFormaddress['country'][$i],
        'zip' => $submittedFormaddress['zip'][$i],
    );
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest you utilise `array_keys` to make the solution a bit less fragile

Comment: This will create array keys starting with `address0`, and not `address1` like the OP indicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please not that i don't know which form fields are submitted so i shouldn't set them manually.your code is good for understanding arrays deeper and a + for it.